# How to fix eslint errors in meteor with react tutorial

Tags: javascript, meteor, eslint

I've followed [meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app), and when I finished I've decided to install [eslint](https://guide.meteor.com/code-style.html#eslint-installing).
Now I see

> Prefer default export  import/prefer-default-export

for this line: `export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');` in `imports/api/tasks.js` file. It contains also some Meteor methods. Here it is full source code: [tasks.js](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos/blob/master/imports/api/tasks.js).

I was trying to fix this eg. with

```
const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
export { Tasks as default };
```

But then browser stopped rendering the view.
Here is the `server/main.js` content, which imports `tasks.js`:

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

How can I fix lint error without breaking applications functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `.eslintrc` file to your project root and adapt the rule:

`{"rules": {"import/prefer-default-export": ["off"]}}`

**UPDATE**:

If you want to keep the rule, then you need to export `Tasks` as default like so:

```
const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
export default Tasks;
```

Now you have to change all the `imports` in the rest of your codebase from a named import to a default import. The named import looks like this

```
import { Tasks } from '/imports/api/tasks';
```

see e.g. [here](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos/blob/fcbce761d12cdf582899a40852309e4acd5277c2/imports/ui/body.js#L5), whereas the new default import has to look like this

```
import Tasks from '/imports/api/tasks';
```

This should do it. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It is an option (+1) but I'd prefer to follow this rule.

Comment: I've made wrong assumption that `Tasks` was imported only in `main.js`. After changing it in `App.jsx`, it properly renders and no lint issues.